# Given an array of integers, find the pair of adjacent elements that has the largest product and return that product

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Given an array of integers, find the pair of adjacent elements that has the largest product and return that product.

and here is my code

```
function adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) {
 var arr = inputArray;
  var x=0;
  var y=0;
  var p=0;
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    x=arr[i];
    y=arr[i+1];
    if(x*y>p){
     p=x*y;
    };
  };
 return p;
};
```

**the problem is all the tests works fine but except the array with the negative product** as it shown in the attached photo
can anyone help .. and thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: The last iteration of that loop sets `y` to `arr[arr.length]`, which is not a valid index.

Comment: The problem is that you start `p` at `0`.  In this case, all products are negative, so you never find a greater one.  If you start at `-Infinity` instead, it looks as though it should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could start with a really large negative value, instead of zero.

```
var p = -Infinity;
```

Answer (score 4):

You are initializing the variable `p` to zero. That means any multiplication values smaller than that are not accepted. Rather set it to the smallest possible integer value:

```
var p = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER;
```

```js
function adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) {
  var arr = inputArray;
  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
  var p = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    x = arr[i];
    y = arr[i + 1];
    if (x * y > p) {
      p = x * y;
    };
  };
  return p;
};

console.log(adjacentElementsProduct([-23, 4, -3, 8, -12]));
```

Answer (score 3):

This is quite simple actually

```
function adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) {
    let max = -Infinity;
    for (let i = 1; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        max = Math.max(inputArray[i] * inputArray[i - 1], max);
    }

    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is quite simple actually

```js
const solution = (inputArray) => Math.max(...inputArray.slice(0, -1).map((n, index) => n * inputArray[index + 1]))

console.log(solution([3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem at first, defining the first max as 0. Then i came up with this:

```
function solution(inputArray) {
    let products = inputArray.map(function(x, index){
        return inputArray[index+1] != undefined? x *inputArray[index+1] : -Infinity;
    })
    return Math.max(...products);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem:
Given an array of integers, find the pair of adjacent elements that has the largest product and return that product. #javascript #arraymethods

```
function solution(inputArray) {
    let productsArr = []; // to hold the products of adjacent elements
    let n = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (i < inputArray.length - 1) 
        {
            productsArr[n] = inputArray[i] * inputArray[i + 1];
            n++;
        }
    }
    return productsArr.reduce((aggr, val) => Math.max(aggr, val)); // to find out the biggest product
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function solution(inputArray: number[]): number {
    var max = -Infinity;
    
    for(var i=0; i+1<inputArray.length; i++)
    {
        if(max<(inputArray[i]*inputArray[i+1])){
            max=inputArray[i]*inputArray[i+1];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

console.log(solution([2,3,6]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple implementation without using any additional variables (actually less), and no special values. Just simple logic.

```js
function adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) {
    var c =inputArray[0]*inputArray[1];
    var p = c;
    for(var i=1;i<inputArray.length;i++){
        console.log(c);
        var c=inputArray[i]*inputArray[i+1];
        if(c > p){
            p=c;
        };
    };
    return p;
};
console.log("minimum product = " + adjacentElementsProduct([-23,4,-3,8,-12]));
```

What I did was, initialize a variable c (current product) with the product of first two elements of the array. And then I declared the variable p and initialize it to c. This way, all other products are compared to this product. Rest is simple.

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to initialize a integer as negative infinity value **-math.inf** and then use the **python** ternary operator **var=true if condition else false** to find the maximum value

code in **python**

```py
def adjacentarray(a):
    maximum=-math.inf
    for i,in range(0,len(a)-1):
        maximum=a[i]*a[i+1] if a[i]*a[i+1]>maximum else maximum
    return maximum
```

code in ***javascript***

```js
function adjacentElementsProduct(a) {
    var maximum=-Infinity;
    for (var i=0;i<a.length-1;i++){
        maximum= a[i]*a[i+1]>maximum?a[i]*a[i+1]:maximum;
    }
    return maximum;
}
```

Comment: Hi, this code doesn't seem to be javascript, as the question is tagged and prompted in the title. Can you please adapt the code to be javascript?

Comment: hi @niccord, I have updated the code in javascript also

Answer (score 0):

### python solution

You can make a loop from 1 to end of your list and do the following arithmetic operations

```py
def solution(inputArray):
    list1 =[]
    for i in range(1,len(inputArray)):
        list1.append(inputArray[i]*inputArray[i-1]) 
    return max(list1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
    function solution(inputArray) {
     let first, second, sum = []
    inputArray.map((arr,index)=>{ 
        first = arr;
        second =  inputArray[index+1]
        if(second == undefined){
            return second
        }
     return sum.push(first * second)
    })
   
  let last =  sum.sort().reduce((pre,next)=> {
     return pre > next ? pre : next
    })
    return last;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
//Kotlin
fun solution(inputArray: MutableList<Int>): Int {
    var result: Int = Int.MIN_VALUE
    for (i in 0..inputArray.size - 2) {
        if (inputArray[i] * inputArray[i + 1] > result)
            result = inputArray[i] * inputArray[i + 1]
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to attempt to answer the question, which is about javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:math';

int solution(List<int> inputArray) {
    //assumption for highest number 
    int highestNumber  = inputArray[0] * inputArray[1] ;
    
    //we'll go through the array to campare the highestNumber
    //with next index
    for(var i = 1 ; i < inputArray.length ; i++){
      highestNumber = max(highestNumber,  inputArray[i] * inputArray[i - 1]);
    }
    return highestNumber;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you could use the reduce method from an array to avoid iterating in a for loop, just like this.

```
function solution(inputArray) {
    let maxProd = []

    inputArray.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
        maxProd.push(accumulator*currentValue)
        
        return currentValue
    },
    );

    return Math.max(...maxProd)
}
```

Once you have in the **maxProd** array the products, you use the spread operator to get the numbers and using *Math.max()* you get the largest

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in PHP that is quite simple.

```
function solution($inputArray) {

$largest = null;
$pos = null;

for($i = 0; $i < count($inputArray) -1; $i++){
    $pos = ($inputArray[$i] * $inputArray[$i+1]);
    if($largest < $pos){
        $largest = $pos;
    }
}
return $largest ?? 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the better solution if you want to find the max product of the adjacent numbers using Typescript.
*Guaranteed constraints:* `2 ≤ inputArray.length ≤ 10` `-1000 ≤ inputArray[i] ≤ 1000`

```
function maxAdjacentProduct(inputArray: number[]): number {
    let maxProduct: number;
    for(let i = 0; i < inputArray.length - 1; i++) {
        let currentProduct: number = inputArray[i] * inputArray[i + 1]
        if(maxProduct === undefined || maxProduct < currentProduct) {
            maxProduct = currentProduct
        }
    }
    return maxProduct;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to create a new array of length (arr.length-1) inside the function and append the products of adjacent numbers to this new array. Then find the largest number in the array and return it. This will solve the problem with negative product.

```
function adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) {
  var arr = inputArray;
  var prodArr[];
  var p;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
    prodArr[i] = arr[i]*arr[i+1];
  };
  for (j=prodArr.length; j--){
  if (prodArr[j] > p) {
      p = prodArr[j];
    };
  return p;
};

console.log(adjacentElementsProduct([-23, 4, -3, 8, -12]));
```

Answer (score -1):

The var **p** which saves the max product should be initialized as small as possible instead of a 0. So that when the product is negative, it will still meet the if condition and save the value.
Here is a C# solution:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] arr = { 1, -4, 3, -6, -7, 0 };
            Console.WriteLine(FindMaxProduct(arr));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
 static int FindMaxProduct(int[] arr) {
            int currentProduct = 0;
            int maxProduct = int.MinValue;
            int a=0, b = 0;
            for (int i = 0, j = i + 1; i < arr.Length - 1 && j < arr.Length; i++, j++)
            {
                currentProduct = arr[i] * arr[j];
                if (currentProduct>maxProduct) {
                    a = arr[i];
                    b = arr[j];
                    maxProduct = currentProduct;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The max product is {0}, the two nums are {1} and {2}.",maxProduct,a,b);
            return maxProduct;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

This should help, wrote it in python. Concept: Pass an empty list, for every consecutive product keep storing it in the list. Then just return the max value.

```py
def consecutive_product_max(a):
    lst2 = []
    for i in range(0, len(a)-1):
        x = a[i] * a[i+1]
        lst2.append(x)
    return max(lst2)
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function solution(inputArray) {
    let f, s, arr = []
    for(let i=0; i<inputArray.length; i++){
        f = inputArray[i]
        s = inputArray[i+1]
        arr.push(f*s)
    }
    let max = arr.sort((a, b) => b - a)
    return max[0]
}

console.log(solution([3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]))
```

Comment: Note that sorting then taking the first element is an inefficient, not to mention inelegant, way to find a maximum.