# Select items in array with Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array with an unset amount of items. Let's say I want to select items `3 - the end of the array`. How would I do this?

Comment: `slice(2)` will get all elements from the 3rd position to the end of the array.  You should have been able to find references to this method with a simple google search.

Comment: take a look to [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) on MDN

Answer (score 0):

You would use the [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method of arrays:

> arr.slice([begin[, end]])

In your case:

```
yourArr.slice(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `filter` method.

If, for example, you have this:

```
let arr = ['bug', 'cat', 'dog', 'flea', 'bat', 'hat', 'rat'];

let newArr = arr.filter((element, index) => index >= 3);

console.log(newArr); // ['flea', 'bat', 'hat', 'rat']
```

You can specify which index you want to select from to the end of the array.

**Credit to Pointy for helping me solve this**

Comment: @CertainPerformance appreciate it but you were right, it was a duplicate question. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46990569/given-an-array-of-integers-find-the-pair-of-adjacent-elements-that-has-the-larg`