# Find the pair of adjacent elements that has the largest product

Tags: r, apply, lapply

Given an array of integers, can I find the pair of adjacent elements that has the largest product and return that product using apply?

Can be done using the apply function?

Expected input:

```
x <- c(3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3)
```

Expected output:

```
adjacent_elements_product(x) = 21
```

Similar posts that may be relevant:
[Given an array of integers, find the pair of adjacent elements that has the largest product and return that product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46990569)

Comment: Provide example input and expected output, also link the posts that might be relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use rolling `apply`

```
max(zoo::rollapply(x, 2, prod))
#[1] 21
```

---

A base R option would be :

```
max(head(x, -1) * tail(x, -1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using base R and a function as in your example:

```
x <- c(3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3)

adjacent_elements_product <- function(x) {
  return(max(x[-1] * x[-length(x)]))
}

adjacent_elements_product(x)
```